# How to set corners colision on a graph with Amcharts4?

Tags: javascript, graph, amcharts, amcharts4

I want to set corners on this graph to prevent that the circles get cropped when I drag.

Graph from Amcharts docs: https://codepen.io/luizgununes/pen/RwqQmQN

I've searched a lot on docs but I didn't found anything helpful. I'm starting to think this is not possible. Also, I don't know exactly what is the name of this kind of graph to help searching.

```
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/plugins/forceDirected.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

```
// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4plugins_forceDirected.ForceDirectedTree);

var networkSeries = chart.series.push(new am4plugins_forceDirected.ForceDirectedSeries())

networkSeries.data = [{
  name: 'Flora',
  children: [{
    name: 'Black Tea', value: 1
  }, {
    name: 'Floral',
    children: [{
      name: 'Chamomile', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Rose', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Jasmine', value: 1
    }]
  }]
}, {
  name: 'Fruity',
  children: [{
    name: 'Berry',
    children: [{
      name: 'Blackberry', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Raspberry', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Blueberry', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Strawberry', value: 1
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Dried Fruit',
    children: [{
      name: 'Raisin', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Prune', value: 1
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Other Fruit',
    children: [{
      name: 'Coconut', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Cherry', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Pomegranate', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Pineapple', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Grape', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Apple', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Peach', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Pear', value: 1
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Citrus Fruit',
    children: [{
      name: 'Grapefruit', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Orange', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Lemon', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Lime', value: 1
    }]
  }]
}, {
  name: 'Sour/Fermented',
  children: [{
    name: 'Sour',
    children: [{
      name: 'Sour Aromatics', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Acetic Acid', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Butyric Acid', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Isovaleric Acid', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Citric Acid', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Malic Acid', value: 1
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Alcohol/Fremented',
    children: [{
      name: 'Winey', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Whiskey', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Fremented', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Overripe', value: 1
    }]
  }]
}, {
  name: 'Green/Vegetative',
  children: [{
    name: 'Olive Oil', value: 1
  }, {
    name: 'Raw', value: 1
  }, {
    name: 'Green/Vegetative',
    children: [{
      name: 'Under-ripe', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Peapod', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Fresh', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Dark Green', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Vegetative', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Hay-like', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Herb-like', value: 1
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Beany', value: 1
  }]
}, {
  name: 'Other',
  children: [{
    name: 'Papery/Musty',
    children: [{
      name: 'Stale', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Cardboard', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Papery', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Woody', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Moldy/Damp', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Musty/Dusty', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Musty/Earthy', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Animalic', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Meaty Brothy', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Phenolic', value: 1
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Chemical',
    children: [{
      name: 'Bitter', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Salty', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Medicinal', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Petroleum', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Skunky', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Rubber', value: 1
    }]
  }]
}, {
  name: 'Roasted',
  children: [{
    name: 'Pipe Tobacco', value: 1
  }, {
    name: 'Tobacco', value: 1
  }, {
    name: 'Burnt',
    children: [{
      name: 'Acrid', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Ashy', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Smoky', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Brown, Roast', value: 1
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Cereal',
    children: [{
      name: 'Grain', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Malt', value: 1
    }]
  }]
}, {
  name: 'Spices',
  children: [{
    name: 'Pungent', value: 1
  }, {
    name: 'Pepper', value: 1
  }, {
    name: 'Brown Spice',
    children: [{
      name: 'Anise', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Nutmeg', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Cinnamon', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Clove', value: 1
    }]
  }]
}, {
  name: 'Nutty/Cocoa',
  children: [{
    name: 'Nutty',
    children: [{
      name: 'Peanuts', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Hazelnut', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Almond', value: 1
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Cocoa',
    children: [{
      name: 'Chocolate', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Dark Chocolate', value: 1
    }]
  }]
}, {
  name: 'Sweet',
  children: [{
    name: 'Brown Sugar',
    children: [{
      name: 'Molasses', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Maple Syrup', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Caramelized', value: 1
    }, {
      name: 'Honey', value: 1
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Vanilla', value: 1
  }, {
    name: 'Vanillin', value: 1
  }, {
    name: 'Overall Sweet', value: 1
  }, {
    name: 'Sweet Aromatics', value: 1
  }]
}];

networkSeries.dataFields.linkWith = "linkWith";
networkSeries.dataFields.name = "name";
networkSeries.dataFields.id = "name";
networkSeries.dataFields.value = "value";
networkSeries.dataFields.children = "children";
networkSeries.links.template.distance = 1;
networkSeries.nodes.template.tooltipText = "{name}";
networkSeries.nodes.template.fillOpacity = 1;
networkSeries.nodes.template.outerCircle.scale = 1;

networkSeries.nodes.template.label.text = "{name}"
networkSeries.fontSize = 8;
networkSeries.nodes.template.label.hideOversized = true;
networkSeries.nodes.template.label.truncate = true;
networkSeries.minRadius = am4core.percent(2);
networkSeries.manyBodyStrength = -5;
networkSeries.links.template.strokeOpacity = 0;
```